# using of possessive pronoun

Tags: pronouns, possessives

1. The house is not only wives but husbands too, the children are not only mothers, fathers too.
2. The house is not only **of** wives but husbands too, the children are not only **of** mothers, fathers too.

Comment: Can you give a little more specific context to the question? I'm not quite sure what the "house" is in this context

Comment: actually I want to say: Newly married couples are expected to start taking equal part in house maintenance and childcare as the house is not only wives but husbands too, the children are not only mothers, fathers too.

Answer (score 1):

In the given context, the correct way of saying this would be:

> The house is not only the wife's house, but also the husband's house too. The children are not only the wife's children, but the husband's children too.

Which would imply that the house and the children don't only belong to the wife, but also belong to the husband, housework doesn't only involve the wife but also the husband, taking care of the children isn't only the wife's job, but the husband's too.

Neither of the sentences mentioned in the question itself are correct. They both have errors which make the sentence make no sense.

Comment: You need an apostrophe on **husband** just as you have it with **wife's**: *husband's*.

Comment: I downvoted only because of your last sentence in which you say the OP's sentences are grammatical. Both sentences have grammatical errors. Your suggestion is good, apart from the error with *husbands*.

Comment: Ah yes, a mere typo I'll fix that

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo thank you for pointing that out I didn't even realise I had written it way differently that I had originally meant, fixed all the grammar errors I noticed

Comment: I have corrected the typo Veraen made in the suggested pattern. since Veraen's suggestion was useful for which i was concern about, so apostrophe error (a minor error typo) was not an issue for me.